# Outlook 2003 is not rendering correctly our MJML code

Tags: email, outlook, responsive-design, mjml

I want to make a responsive email template with [MJML](https://mjml.io/), it looks good on most of the email rendering clients, but (of course) Outlook 2003 is doing it differently, as you can see in the image:
Outlook 2003 is rendering both, the mobile and the desktop version.

[image: outlook rendering both, mobile and desktop]

The complete code is here which you can try here: https://mjml.io/try-it-live/Bk5Gu1w9L

```
<mjml owa="desktop">
  <mj-head>
    <mj-breakpoint width="320px" />
    <mj-style>

        @media screen and (max-width:320px) {
            .show_on_desktop td{
                display: none !important;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (min-width:321px) {
            .show_on_mobile td{
                display: none !important;

            }
        }

        .show_on_mobile td {
            mso-hide: all;
            font-size: 0;
            max-height: 0;
            line-height: 0;
      }
    </mj-style>


  </mj-head>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-raw><!--[if !mso]><\!--></mj-raw>
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column css-class="show_on_mobile">
        <mj-image src="https://www.ecom-ex.com/fileadmin/user_upload/images/products/one-pager/gallery/ex-handy_10_dz1dz2/ex-handy_10_dz1_teaser_1.png"></mj-image>
        <mj-text>show on mobile</mj-text>
      </mj-column>
      </mj-section>
    <mj-raw><!-- <![endif]--></mj-raw>


    <mj-section>
      <mj-column css-class="show_on_desktop">
        <mj-image src="http://c64os.com/resources/c64c-system.jpg"></mj-image>
        <mj-text>show on desktop</mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>

  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

The rendering is tested via [EmailOnAcid](https://app.emailonacid.com) which does not provide a free account to play around.

We tried many versions, this was the best looking so far, but Outlook 2003 (and some others) are showing it not as we were hoping for.

We are discussing about ignoring some old clients as Outlook 2003, but a solution instead of ignoring it, would be really nice.

Comment: As I understand it, MTML was introduced in 2016.  Why do you think Outlook 2003 will be able to handle it?

Comment: @TonyDallimore - MJML is a way to design emails responsive. hava a look at https://mjml.io - the outpout is pure html, nothing else.

Comment: I have not used Outlook 2003 for about three years.  I do not recall the version of HTML it supported being updated.  Does MJML restrict itself to an early version of HTML?  There are sites that tell you what versions of HTML each browser and email package support.  They may give you a some idea of the tags that are giving you a problem.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Outlook does not support `display:none`  that's why you have to work around, as I did above. but this Outlook version is not rendering it correct, as the others Outlooks versions. I don't say, I MUST have it correct at the end, but it would be nice, if it is.
Else users which use this really old client will see the content twice.
And please have a look what MJML does, your questions let me think, you don't know it yet.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Two sites: https://caniuse.email/   https://caniemail.com/

Answer (score 1):

I know this conversation dates a bit, but @TonyDallimore : would you try to run a 2020 game on Windows XP?

Even if MJML is pure HTML, HTML also evolved since 2003 ;-) Even Microsoft stopped supporting 2k3 quite a while ago.

It's as if you were asking the guy at the gas station for leaded gas, because your 1970's car was originally made for that ;-)

If you are the Outlook 2003 user, may I simply suggest you try to get something a little bit more recent? there are tons of freeware you can use. And many of them are as complete if not more than Outlook 2003 and can import your past and present emails into your new mail manager :-)

If someone else is the Outlook 2003 user, I don't know how close you may be to that person, or even if you know of anyone who personally uses that version, but I personally would tell you to just NOT worry about them.

Maybe you could put a friendly note at the top and/or bottom of your email that for security purposes, outdated email managers "may" not be supported my the MJML format of the email. ;-)

Hoping this helps you understand a bit clearer the situation,
merlinregis

Answer (score 0):

There's a related discussion at https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/issues/1182

Nothing against support here, but (FYI) there's lots of MJML Support for questions just like this at https://slack.mjml.io.

Good luck.