# Zurb foundation for emails: Hiding some containers for small devices

Tags: email, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, responsive, inky

when I was [questioning on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731921/outlook-2003-is-not-rendering-correctly-our-mjml-code) how to solve my problem with [mjml.io](https://mjml.io) and after some research I found that there is also [ZURB Foundation emails](https://get.foundation/emails) which should work perfectly on Outlook 2003 (as mentioned on their website).
So I tried to create the same behaviour as I was doing on this [MJML.io Tryout page](https://mjml.io/try-it-live/Bk5Gu1w9L).
My problem is:
I only see `show-for-large` and `hide-for large` in the CSS.
But I can't see anything which will `show-for-small` and `hide-for-small`....

```
<container class="show-for-large">
  <row>
    <columns  >
      <img src="http://c64os.com/resources/c64c-system.jpg">
    </columns>

  </row>
</container>

<container class="hide-for-large">
  <row>
    <columns>
      <img src="https://www.ecom-ex.com/fileadmin/user_upload/images/products/one-pager/gallery/ex-handy_10_dz1dz2/ex-handy_10_dz1_teaser_1.png">
    </columns>

  </row>
</container>
```

It works for Desktop, but for mobile it shows both :-(
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is only one breakpoint `$global-breakpoint` (`$global-width + $global-gutter`) in Foundation Emails (see https://github.com/foundation/foundation-emails/blob/2474651b1de029aea9f5830e95842753bf0242e3/scss/settings/_settings.scss#L40).

`show-for-large` is the same as `hide-for-small` and`hide-for-large` is the same as `show-for-small` (regarding the logic).

If you need more classes you would have to add / create your own helper classes if you need these classes as we provide only the one which use `$global-breakpoint`.

See https://github.com/foundation/foundation-emails/blob/develop/scss/components/_visibility.scss

Comment: hmmm what is then wrong in the example above?
If i go to desktop size, I see only the desktop
but if i make it smaller, I see both, which I don't want, I only wanna see the mobile

Comment: Please check the elements in your browser using the inspect function and the applied styles. It could be different when the styles are inlined / not inlined.

Comment: Ah I think I know what the issue may be. We used `!important` in the last release but changed / fixed this in the `develop` branch. See also https://github.com/foundation/foundation-emails/issues/999

Comment: Ok, so I will wait for the new release. because we are already on 2.2.1 ....